# Values of Pandas DataFrame merged after resampling

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-resample

I have tried to resample a dataframe from minutes to daily. For this I used the following lines:

```
df_1d = df.resample('D')['Value'].sum().asfreq(freq='D').reset_index()
df_1d.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df_1d['DateTime']), inplace=True)
df_1d = df_1d.drop('DateTime', axis=1)
df_1d.drop(df_1d.loc[df_1d['Value']=='0.00'].index, inplace=True)
df_1d.dropna(subset='Value', inplace=True)
```

My DataFrame df has two columns one called 'DateTime', containing timestamps in format *%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S*. The other contains values like *0.01, 0.05* and *0.25*.
The Code written so far should resample the Values, calculate the sum for each day and reset the index afterwards.
Then I want to set the Index again as a DatetimeIndex and drop off the now unsused column *DateTime* as there is now an index with this name.
Now I want to see only those rows, where *Value* is not 0. And at the end drop off all NaN-Values found in column *Value*.

This doesn't work as it should. At least the resampled dataframe looks like this:

```
            Value
DateTime
2021-09-06  0.010.050.25
```

It seems like my code just merge the rows for each interval instead of calculating a sum.

I also tried to use a simplier code.

```
df_1d = df.resample('D').sum(min_count=1).asfreq(freq='D').dropna()
```

But with this I got the same result.

Does anyone knows where I made a mistake?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
My desired output should look like this:

```
            Value
DateTime
2021-09-06  0.31
```

Comment: Please share a sample of the data (you can use fake values), rather than describing it

Answer (score 0):

Given the inputs of `0.01`, `0.05`, and `0.25` from your explanation, along with your sample output of `0.010.050.25`, it is clear that the values in your dataframe are strings of floats instead of actual floats (so the `sum` operation will concatenate them).  You can convert this column with `pd.to_numeric` with something like the following example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['A'] = pd.Series(['0.01', '0.05', '0.25'])
print(df.sum())
# A    0.010.050.25
# dtype: object
df['A'] = pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce')
print(df.sum())
# A    0.31
# dtype: float64
```